# Glashow-Weinberg-Salam (GWS) Theory for Gauge Boson Masses

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, higgs, weak-interaction, electroweak

I am supposed to find the mass of the $W^\pm$ and $Z$ bosons from the following covariant derivative:

$$D_\mu = \partial\mu - \frac{ig_1}{2}B^\mu -ig_2t^iW^{i\mu} $$

and from

$\mathcal{L}_{kin.  Higgs}=(D_\mu\Phi^\dagger)(D_\mu\Phi)+\frac{1}{2}(D_\mu H)^\dagger (D_\mu H)$

where:

$B_\mu$ is the $U(1)_Y$ gauge boson;

$g_1$ is the hypercharge coupling;

$g_2$ is the weak coupling;

$W^{i\mu}$ are the $SU(2)_L$ gauge bosons;

$t^i$ the generators of $SU(2)_L$ in the appropriate representation.

I know I must calculate the first half of the lagrangian equation, according to the Glashow-Weinberg-Salam Theory of Weak Interactions (Peskin & Schroeder 20.2), but I am not certain how to do so.

I think the $t^i$ (the generators of $SU(2)$) can be represented as $i\sigma_i$, where $\sigma$ is a Pauli matrix but if this is the case I don't know how to introduce the Pauli Matrices into the equation.
Am I supposed to only introduce one of Pauli matrices? Am I supposed to introduce one at the time and solve the equation three different times?

Answer (score 1):

The covariant derivative you wrote down contains a sum over the $\mathrm{SU(2)}$ indices, so you need to use all Pauli matrices:

$$W_\mu^i \sigma^i = \begin{pmatrix}
W_\mu^3 & W_\mu^1 - i W_\mu^2 \\
W_\mu^1 + i W_\mu^2 & -W_\mu^3
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thank you that was great help.
But how would I use that for H which is a triplet (3x1)  as I can't multiply a 2x2 by a 3x1.

Comment: If $H$ is a triplet field you need to use the $3 \times 3$ representation of $\mathrm{SU(2)}$ and its associated generators.

Comment: @DavidH, what about the Yukawa coupling between the triplet H and the left-handed isospin doublet?